# How to survive "delayed variable expansion" in a Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%i in ('echo aaa/') do set REPO=%%i
if "%REPO%"=="" (
  echo No input
) else (
  echo %REPO:~-1%
  echo %REPO:~0,-1%
  if %REPO:~-1%==/ set REPO=%REPO:~0,-1%
  echo %REPO%
)

endlocal
```

Please, observe:

```
c:\dev\shunra\GlobalLibrary\Server>c:\Utils\hgbackup.cmd
/
aaa
aaa/

c:\dev\shunra\GlobalLibrary\Server>
```

What is going on?

**EDIT**

Note, that I am assigning to REPO something that evaluates to "aaa", hence I expect it to print "aaa", not "aaa/". It drives me crazy.

**EDIT2**

Apparently, here is the culprit (from help on the set command):

```
Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been
added.  This support is always disabled by default, but may be
enabled/disabled via the /V command line switch to CMD.EXE.  See CMD /?

Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around
the limitations of the current expansion which happens when a line
of text is read, not when it is executed.  The following example
demonstrates the problem with immediate variable expansion:

    set VAR=before
    if "%VAR%" == "before" (
        set VAR=after
        if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
    )

would never display the message, since the %VAR% in BOTH IF statements
is substituted when the first IF statement is read, since it logically
includes the body of the IF, which is a compound statement.  So the
IF inside the compound statement is really comparing "before" with
"after" which will never be equal.  Similarly, the following example
will not work as expected:

    set LIST=
    for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
    echo %LIST%

in that it will NOT build up a list of files in the current directory,
but instead will just set the LIST variable to the last file found.
Again, this is because the %LIST% is expanded just once when the
FOR statement is read, and at that time the LIST variable is empty.
So the actual FOR loop we are executing is:

    for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i

which just keeps setting LIST to the last file found.

Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different
character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at
execution time.  If delayed variable expansion is enabled, the above
examples could be written as follows to work as intended:

    set VAR=before
    if "%VAR%" == "before" (
        set VAR=after
        if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
    )

    set LIST=
    for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
    echo %LIST%
```

But I tried using the `!` sign, still it does not work for me. I use get `!` printed on the screen or the wrong result again.

Comment: What output did *you* expect? What is your batch script supposed to do?

Comment: looks right. What did you intend it to do?

Comment: Anyone cares to provide the explanations for the close votes?

Comment: The vague title of the question is unlikely to help future visitors to the site. (For the answer to your question, see "delayed variable expansion")

Comment: @RaymondChen - I tried fixing it with the `!` - no dice. Can you give a working example as the answer?

Comment: From your own **EDIT2** _This support is always disabled by default_, so you need to enable it first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments, and in your edited question, you need delayed expansion.

Delayed expansion must be enabled before you can use it. Within a batch script you can use `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in ('echo aaa/') do set REPO=%%i
if "%REPO%"=="" (
  echo No input
) else (
  echo %REPO:~-1%
  echo %REPO:~0,-1%
  if %REPO:~-1%==/ set REPO=%REPO:~0,-1%
  echo !REPO!
)

endlocal
```

**EDIT**

The above fails if the IN() clause is changed such that REPO is undefined. For example: `in (echo.)`

It fails because the entire IF/ELSE construct must have valid syntax, even it the ELSE clause will not be executed.

If REPO is undefined, then

```
if %REPO:~-1%==/ set REPO=%REPO:~0,-1%
```

expands to

```
if ~-1REPO:~0,-1
```

which is invalid syntax.

The problem again is solved by using delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in ('echo.') do set REPO=%%i
if "%REPO%"=="" (
  echo No input
) else (
  echo %REPO:~-1%
  echo %REPO:~0,-1%
  if !REPO:~-1!==/ set REPO=%REPO:~0,-1%
  echo !REPO!
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Almost there. It works for `echo aaa/` and for `echo aaa`, but not for `echo.`.

Comment: @mark - `echo.` prints a blank line, and a FOR /F loop always ignores blank lines.

Comment: Why does it matter? If you insert `echo "x%REPO%x"` immediately after the FOR, then it will print "xx" in case of `echo.`, which is correct. Then why the IF does not work? I mean you solved the delayed expansion problem, so what is it now?

Comment: This is crazy! Why couldn't they do it like in bash?

Answer (score 0):

> Note, that I am assigning to REPO something that evaluates to "aaa"

Actually, you're *conditionally* assigning something.  Have you testing whether the then-part is actually executing (for example, `echo If Entered`).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (just an extract from my whole script)

```
choice /C 1234567H /M "Select an option or ctrl+C to cancel"
set _dpi=%ERRORLEVEL%

if "%_dpi%" == "8" call :helpme && goto menu 

for /F "tokens=%_dpi%,*" %%1 in ("032 060 064 096 0C8 0FA 12C") do set _dpi=%%1
echo _dpi:%_dpi%:
```